# Getting an unexpected newline when printing lines from a file

Tags: python, regex, append, line

Pretty straight forward question here...I'm looking to append my regex match to the same line, not a new line in the file. I thought I had done this correctly, but the result is still printing to a new line:

Result:

```
1,2,BreakingBad,4,5,6...
,BreakingBad
```

What I want:

```
1,2,BreakingBad,4,5,6...,.BreakingBad
```

Current Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import sys

file = open("/home/test", "r")
newfile = open("/home/testresults","w")

def regex():
        #old_stdout = sys.stdout
        #sys.stdout = newfile
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
                regex = re.search(r'(BreakingBad)',line)
                if regex:
                        print line + "," + regex.group(1)

try:
        regex()
finally:
        file.close()
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to modify: `print line + "," + regex.group(1)` to: `print line.strip() + "," + regex.group(1)`

Comment: `line` is one of the lines from the `readlines()` call, so it will be newline-terminated. You probably want to add a `line = line.rstrip()` before your print.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few more things that are not overly Pythonic, though they'd be more suited in a code review.
Since it would become too long for a comment, I just put it as an answer.

Summary:

- use the `with` context manager. This saves you the hassle of `try ... finally` for making sure the file is closed afterwards.
- don't use `file` as a variable name: it's a reserved class name (for a file object, no less)
- don't use global variables: just pass the filename to the `regex()` function
- iterate over the file object. That saves you the call to `readlines()` and then iterating over the lines. Iterating over a file does the same thing in one go.

  This iteration can also save memory, since it doesn't read the full file in one go, but line by line. See for example [this post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html) for more information.
- you don't need a regex for a simple word search. Generally, try avoiding the regex first and see what other options exist (there are quite a few useful methods to `str`).

  The usual saying about regexes goes something like

  > > > I have a problem. I'll try a regular expression.
  > > >
  > > > ...
  > > >
  > > > Now I have two problems

  ([here's one post on this topic](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) .)

  In this case, a simple `if word in sentence` form can do the trick.

This could give the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def run(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:  # "r" mode is default
        for line in lines:
            if 'BreakingBad' in line:
                print line.rstrip('\n') + "," + 'BreakingBad'

run("/home/test")
```

Note that I'm explicitly `rstrip`ping the newline only: if you'd use just `rstrip()`, it strips any whitespace character from the right, including spaces and tabs. That may be intended, but it's not clear from the question.

Further: since you open a file for writing (but don't use it, that is, it's not essential to your question): you can combine files in the `with` statement:

```
with open(filename) as infile, open(newfilename, "w") as outfile:
    <whatever>
```

Comment: Another part is that we don't need regex here, `regex = re.search(r'(BreakingBad)',line); if regex:` can just be `if 'BreakingBad' in line`.

Comment: @KevinGuan good point. Since I've turned this into a code review, I'll edit that into my answer to try and be complete.

Answer (score 1):

The file contains the string with a newline attached to it. Python reads it as:

`lines = '1,2,BreakingBad,4,5,6...\n'`


Therefore when you concatenate, the string is:

`1,2,BreakingBad,4,5,6...\n,BreakingBad`


 What you really want is to remove the newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import sys


file = open("/home/test", "r")
newfile = open("/home/testresults","w")

def regex():
        #old_stdout = sys.stdout
        #sys.stdout = newfile
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
                regex = re.search(r'(BreakingBad)',line)
                if regex:
                        print line.strip() + "," + regex.group(1)

try:
        regex()
finally:
        file.close()
```

Comment: I don't think Python "adds a new line at the end": it simply reads the newline *as well* from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the newline from the line:

```
print line.rstrip() + "," + regex.group(1)
```

You could/might also just use slicing, but this would depend if there is or not a newline in the end of the line:

```
print line[:-1] + "," + regex.group(1) #if ends with '\n'
```

I wouldn't do this case because you'd have to know EXACTLY how everyfile is formatted, and if there's any error at any moment, you could have a difficult to find bug.

Comment: Your comment "if ends with '\n'" is very essential, and may require an actual if statement before the print line: readlines() will not read a newline for the final line, if the file doesn't end with a newline. Thus, there is a chance that for the last line, you'd be stripping some other character with that slicing syntax. As for `rstrip()`: that would strip spaces, tabs etc, next to a possible newline. Which may or may not be intended, but it doesn't just take care of the newline *only*.